$\text{rank}\left({\mathbf A}^2\right)+\text{rank}\left( {\mathbf B}^2\right)\ge2\text{rank}\left(\mathbf{{AB}}\right).$

Let matrices $\mathbf A,\mathbf B$ satisfy
$$\mathbf A+\mathbf B+\mathbf A\mathbf B=0$$
Prove that
$$\text{rank}\left({\mathbf A}^2\right)+\text{rank}\left({\mathbf B}^2\right)\ge2\text{rank}\left(\mathbf{AB}\right).$$

Is this right?
My attempt: $(I+A)(I+B)=I$, so $AB=BA$. $A,B$ can be simultanenously upper triangular. So $tr(A^2)+tr(B^2)-2tr(AB)=\sum_i(a_i-b_i)^2\ge 0$.
What about the rank? Can we prove or give a contradiction?

Since $B=(I+A)^{-1}-I=-A(I+A)^{-1}$, we have
$
\operatorname{rank}(AB)
=\operatorname{rank}\left(A^2 (I+A)^{-1} \right)
=\operatorname{rank}(A^2).
$
If we interchange the roles of $A$ and $B$, we also have $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(B^2)$. Therefore $\operatorname{rank}(A^2)+\operatorname{rank}(B^2)=2\operatorname{rank}(AB)$. (Yes, equality holds.)
Put it another way, let $X=I+A$. Since $X$ is invertible,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{rank}(A^2)+\operatorname{rank}(B^2)
&=\operatorname{rank}((X-I)^2)+\operatorname{rank}((X^{-1}-I)^2)\\
&=\operatorname{rank}((X-I)^2X^{-1})+\operatorname{rank}(X(X^{-1}-I)^2)\\
&=\operatorname{rank}((X-I)(I-X^{-1}))+\operatorname{rank}((I-X)(X^{-1}-I))\\
&=2\operatorname{rank}((X-I)(X^{-1}-I))\\
&=2\operatorname{rank}(AB).
\end{align*}
